# Create Duplicate Rows and Change Values in Specific Columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to create x amount of duplicates based on a row in the dataframe and change a single or multi variables from specific columns. The rows are then added to the end of the same dataframe.

```
  A B C D E F
0 1 1 0 1 1 0
1 2 2 1 1 1 0
2 2 2 1 1 1 0
3 2 2 1 1 1 0
4 1 1 0 1 1 0 <- Create 25 Duplicates of this row (4) and change variable C to 1
5 1 1 0 1 1 0
6 2 2 1 1 1 0
7 2 2 1 1 1 0
8 2 2 1 1 1 0 
9 1 1 0 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I repeat only 10 times to keep length of result reasonable.

```
#    Number of repeats |
#                      v
df.append(df.loc[[4] * 10].assign(C=1), ignore_index=True)

    A  B  C  D  E  F
0   1  1  0  1  1  0
1   2  2  1  1  1  0
2   2  2  1  1  1  0
3   2  2  1  1  1  0
4   1  1  0  1  1  0
5   1  1  0  1  1  0
6   2  2  1  1  1  0
7   2  2  1  1  1  0
8   2  2  1  1  1  0
9   1  1  0  1  1  0
10  1  1  1  1  1  0
11  1  1  1  1  1  0
12  1  1  1  1  1  0
13  1  1  1  1  1  0
14  1  1  1  1  1  0
15  1  1  1  1  1  0
16  1  1  1  1  1  0
17  1  1  1  1  1  0
18  1  1  1  1  1  0
19  1  1  1  1  1  0
```

---

Per comments, try:

```
df.append(df.loc[[4] * 10].assign(**{'C': 1}), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Only when it's short enough (-: Thanks.

Comment: @piRSquared putting the feature name __C__ gets me __invalid syntax__ and putting  __C__ in quotes gets me __keyword can't be an expression__, adding __C = 1__ in quotation gets me __assign() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given__

Comment: If it is really `'C'` then it should work as I have it.  If it is a phrase broken by whitespace then we have to make a slight change.  Let me know what column name actually is.

Comment: @Victor I've updated the post with an alternative.  In this example, replace `'C'` with `'whatever my column name is'`

Comment: @piRSquared My friend. This is some dark magic. The per comment has made it work

Comment: @piRSquared sorry ! A quick question, when I try to duplicate without chaning any value using __df.append(df.loc[[4] * 10])__ I get an error. Is there a right way to make exact duplictes without changing any values/variables

Comment: In current versions of Pandas `.append()` has been deprecated. The recommended approach is to use `pd.concat()`, which would make the example above look like `df = pd.concat([df, df.loc[[4] * 10].assign(**{'C': 1})])`.

Answer (score 2):

I  am using `repeat` and `reindex`

```
s=df.iloc[[4],] # pick the row you want to do repeat
s=s.reindex(s.index.repeat(45))# repeat the row by the giving number 
#s=pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[4,].tolist()]*25) if need enhance the speed , using this line replace the above
s.loc[:,'C']=1 # change the value
pd.concat([df,s]) #append to the original df
```

Comment: what is happening at each step

Comment: @Victor add explanation

Comment: Thank you @wen I appreciate it buddy !

Comment: @Victor yw :-) happy coding

Comment: the index does not change, but it seems like the index is also copied rather than continuing from the last index in the dataframe.

Comment: @Victor for me keeping the original index is more valuable , since  we can easily using `reset_index()` get a new index . :-)