# Replicate each row in pandas dataframe and change values of some columns based on a list

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
     my_id    val_a_b    val_a    val_c
0     id_1    rat|white   rat      1
1     id_2    dog|brown   dog      0
```

and a list like this:

```
val_a_list = ['rat', 'dog', 'cow']
```

I want to replicate each row multiple times and replace the value in columns `val_a_b` and `val_a` based on each value in `val_a_list` (except when the value in `val_a` is the same as the element in `val_a_list`), keeping the values of all the other columns the same.

desired dataframe:

```
     my_id    val_a_b    val_a    val_c
0     id_1    rat|white   rat      1
1     id_2    dog|brown   dog      0
2     id_1    dog|white   dog      1
3     id_1    cow|white   cow      1  
4     id_2    rat|brown   rat      0
5     id_2    cow|brown   cow      0
```

Note: rows 2 and 3 are based on row 0 and rows 4 and 5 are based on row 1.

This is the code I have, which iterates over each row. I'm looking for a better solution:

```
def replicate_val_a_in_df(df, val_a_list):
    df_base_size = df.shape[0]
    for i in range(df_base_size):
        for new_val_a in val_a_list:
            val_a_b = df.iloc[i]['val_a_b']
            val_a_b_parts = val_a_b.split('|')
            original_val_a = val_a_b_parts[0]
            if new_val_a != original_val_a:
                val_b = val_a_b_parts[1]
                new_val_a_b = "|".join([new_val_a, val_b])
                df.append(df.iloc[i], ignore_index=True)
                df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('val_a')] = new_val_a
                df.iloc[-1, df.columns.get_loc('val_a_b')] = new_val_a_b
    return df
```

I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49674219/create-duplicate-rows-and-change-values-in-specific-columns) but it sets the same column value in all the duplicate rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you can create a `dict` so you can `map` and `explode`, and finally reconstruct column b:

```
d = {i: val_a_list for i in val_a_list}
df = df.assign(val_a=df["val_a"].map(d).fillna(df["val_a"])).explode("val_a")
df["val_a_b"] = df["val_a"]+"|"+df["val_a_b"].str.split("|").str[-1]

print (df)

  my_id    val_a_b val_a  val_c
0  id_1  rat|white   rat      1
0  id_1  dog|white   dog      1
0  id_1  cow|white   cow      1
1  id_2  rat|brown   rat      0
1  id_2  dog|brown   dog      0
1  id_2  cow|brown   cow      0
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That solves part of my problem. I also wish to modify the column `val_a_b` (as posted in the example in my question)

Comment: Sure, edited above to reflect the changes.

Comment: Thanks, this is a rather neat solution!